# Can I just cap the red wire from a dual switch to install a ceiling fan without a light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I am replacing a ceiling light with a ceiling fan NO light. There is a dual switch at the wall to accommodate a ceiling fan with a light. There are 4 wires at the ceiling ground, red, black and white. My question is, can I use the ground, black and white wires for the fan and is it safe to just cap the red wire with a nut?

Comment: Will there still be a wall switch in the usual place that operates a light in the room?  Or will you now need to switch floor lamps etc. manually?

Comment: Going to floor lamps

Answer (score 1):

Nope, can't do it.

Code absolutely requires a wall switch in the room **that works**.

There's a variance that lets you have that wall switch operate a receptacle, and then you're supposed to plug in a floor lamp and leave it switched on 24x7 at the lamp (or just remove the switch knob; that's what I do).  However no, you can't have **only** lights which must be operated at the lamp, with a phone, what have you.

You'll either need a different fan, a light kit for this fan, a ceiling light elsewhere in the room, or the switch must operate a receptacle.  (there aren't Code police who go around checking to see if you actually plug a lamp into it lol.  But you will certainly have problems when you sell the house; it'll get redflagged and you'll have to fix it, right in the middle of the hustle and bustle of the property sale).

Answer (score 0):

Safe, yes, well maybe not to the mental health of people flipping the wrong switch . You may want to consider removing the switch and putting in a [switch filler](https://www.fruitridgetools.com/electrical/wallplates/blank-plates/standard-size/leviton-ivory-blank-toggle-switch-wall-plate-filler-insert-80700-i/) to not frustrate people.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll check out a switch filler, right now I have tape over it :(

Comment: Got the filler.  What do I do with the wires that were connected to the switch I remove? Do I just cap them too?

Comment: If you have just two wires then cap them off, if one end has multiple wires then those wires will need to be connected together.